# Difference between “réveiller” and “éveiller”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

The two verbs *réveiller* and *éveiller*. Both are commonly defined to mean "to wake up" or to "awaken", and likewise the adjectival forms (i.e. participles)  *réveillé(e)* and *éveillé(e)* both often are defined to mean "awake". Is there any difference between how I'm supposed to use these two words, or are they truly identical?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They can be interchangeable at times, not always. Here's a good attempt at defining the difference :

> Éveiller, c'est tirer normalement du sommeil (...) Réveiller, c'est
>   aussi éveiller, mais en faisant quelque effort inhabituel pour faire
>   cesser le sommeil

[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9veiller)

(Very approximative translation: *Éveiller* is to draw someone out of their sleep, *réveiller* is also to draw someone out of their sleep, but with uncommon effort to break sleepiness.)

I think in all literal senses *réveiller* could always be used, but not *éveiller*.
I would say indifferently: « *je dors mal, je me réveille souvent la nuit / Je m'éveille souvent la nuit* ».

But  I would say *un bruit à réveiller les morts* ("a noise that would awaken the dead"), and I would not say *éveiller* here.

*Éveiller* will be more easily used in the figurative sense. See the song *[Il est cinq heures, Paris s'éveille](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_est_cinq_heures,_Paris_s%27%C3%A9veille)*. And in that example, it gives a poetical touch that *réveiller* wouldn't have.
*Éveiller* will also be used in the sense of create/engender ( a feeling for example): « La vue de ce tableau a éveillé en moi une immense tristesse »

We'd say of a child « il est bien éveillé pour son âge » ("He's bright for his age") and we would not say that he's « bien réveillé » in that case.

(Réponse qui est loin d'être complète, la question a éveillé en moi des tas de réflexions que je vais ruminer. This answer is far from complete, the question engendered lots of thoughts that I have to ponder about.)

Comment: En effet l'éveil va jusqu'à l'Éveil des mystiques et passe par toutes les nuances qui vont du rêve à l'état de veille ; réveiller est une demande de revenir à cet état de veille, à faire remonter les mémoires enfouies.

Comment: Est-ce que _réveiller_ pourrait être une action instantanée (tirer du sommeil) et _éveiller_ un processus vers l'état de veille ou de réceptivité maximale aux stimuli de son environnement? En ce sens, réveiller les morts est déjà qqch, et un enfant éveillé a fait bien du chemin dans sa compréhension du monde et sa réactivité par rapport aux évènements.